# Codeception, Laravel, Acceptance tests

Tags: laravel, codeception

I'm developping an acceptance test with Codeception Laravel 5.

I see in the docs that module Laravel 5 should not be used in acceptance tests.

Now, I would like to use function like: Auth::xxx, factory(User::class)->create(), etc... but those functions are not recognized.

I can use them in my funcional tests, because I include Laravel 5 Module.

Does it mean I will not be able to use them in acceptance test, or is there a trick to do it???

Answer (score 3):

The documentation clearly outlines the answer to your question:

> You should not use this module for acceptance tests. If you want to use Laravel functionality with your acceptance tests, for example to do test setup, you can initialize the Laravel functionality by adding the following lines of code to your suite _bootstrap.php file:

So this is what you add:

```
require 'bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require 'bootstrap/app.php';
$app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');
$app->instance('request', new \Illuminate\Http\Request);
$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')->bootstrap();
```

This means you `can` use the Laravel functionality in your Acceptance Tests, however, you can't use the `Codeception Laravel 5` module for your Acceptance Tests.

Hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: I already have it in my bootstrap file, but when I dd(Auth::user()) for inst, I get null

Comment: So I'm a little bit confused

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro Hmm, that is an interesting issue. It would seem as if there's another issue in the Acceptance Test, then.

Answer (score 1):

When in acceptance testing, you have two instances, yours (codeception) and the app's (website).

This means anything `laravel` you use in your instance won't work in the app's instance.

Here `Auth::check()` has no meaning, as acceptance testing must be decoupled from the app. You should assert if you are seeing `Log In` or `Log Out` in the rendered html for example.

Eloquent is the only thing you can get away with when in acceptance testing.